# How can I get a facebook post vs a facebook status from the facebook python sdk

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to access a user's posts from their wall using the [python sdk](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/blob/master/facebook.py). I want the [POST](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) object not the [STATUS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/) object. Does anyone know how I would do this? Using get_object(id) returns the status object, not the post object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently if you append the userid and the postid, it returns the post instead of the status objects.

So for example: `get_object("100006765630328_1380118238890351")` will return a POST object, whereas `get_object("1380118238890351")`will return a STATUS object.

I posted a fuller description here:
http://bugsnpieces.blogspot.com/2013/09/facebook-post-vs-status-objects.html